# make variable name cannot contain +?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It seems that makefile variable cannot contain `+`. My environment: Ubuntu 14 LTS, GNU Make 3.81, bash.

```
G++=g++ -std=c++11
test: 
    $(G++) a.cpp -o a

test1:
    g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -o a
```

`make test1`  successes, while `make test` failes with error

```
make: aa.cpp: Command not found
```

I find the following in "GNU make" book.

> > A variable name may be any sequence of characters not containing ‘:’, ‘#’, ‘=’, or white-
> >     space. However, variable names containing characters other than letters, numbers, and
> >     underscores should be considered carefully, as in some shells they cannot be passed through
> >     the environment to a sub-make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that works ok. Your problem is a make parsing error.

```
G++=echo
B++:=echo

test: 
    $(G++) a.cpp -o a

test1:
    echo a.cpp -o a

test2:
    $(G+) a.cpp -o a

test3:
    $(B++) a.cpp -o a
```

Run:

```
$ make test
a.cpp -o a
make: a.cpp: Command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127
$ make test1
echo a.cpp -o a
a.cpp -o a
$ make test2
echo a.cpp -o a
a.cpp -o a
$ make test3
echo a.cpp -o a
a.cpp -o a
```

The issue is that make is seeing `G++=echo` as `G+ += echo` and not `G++ = echo`. The fix is either to use `G++:=echo` to force the parsing to see `:=` or add a space `G++ =echo`.

Comment: Ahaa. so `+=` is treated as an operator on variables. such a caveat for begineers. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a parsing error: it's expected behavior.  The makefile is ambiguous and make is interpreting one way while you wanted it to be interpreted a different way. The simple, always-works solution is to include whitespace around the variable assignment operator: `G++ = echo`

Comment: "error" was not intended pejoratively or as indication of a bug in make. The issue is a parsing "error" in that the parsing did not match the intended expectations and as such the author made an error.